# Selenium plugin for Jenkins fails to copy jar file to slave

Tags: selenium, jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins, selenium-grid

I have taken the [Selenium-plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-plugin) project and updated it to the latest webdrivers.

I have compiled and installed the hpi file on Jenkins and started the Selenium hub.

In the hpi file i can see the whole selenium-server-standalone.jar file.

For some reason, when i try to start the nodes, the selenium-server-standalone.jar is copied to the nodes but with 0 size.

I am able to start the selenium nodes manually as a workaround, but it misses the whole point of the plugin.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i suspected, it was related to permissions.
Turns out that Jenkins is blocking by default some of the agent commands and needs to be whitelisted:

Go to http://jenkins_server_url:port/administrativeMonitor/slaveToMasterAccessControl/rule and add `allow all /.*` to "File Access Rules".

[This thread](https://github.com/jenkinsci/selenium-plugin/issues/118) was very helpful to figure this out.
Thanks to
[dmitryyurasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6403687/dmitryyurasov)

Comment: You should accept your answer to help close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Leon Proskurov's solution did not work for me. What I did instead was manually copy the jars from C:\Users\[user]\.jenkins\plugins\selenium\WEB-INF\lib to the slave agent's remote root directory. I was then able to start Selenium Grid on the slave agent.